# Can a holomorphic function $f$ can be a product of $z$ and some $g$ that $g$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Can a holomorphic function $f$ at $D(0,1)$ can we present $f$ as $f=zg(z)$ where $g$ is holomoprhic and why?

Comment: Take $f$ to be constant.

Comment: $zg(z)$ has a zero at $0$. Does $f$?

Comment: why is $f$ constant? and I don't know if $f(0) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if and only if $f(0)=0$. It is clear that if $f(z)=zg(z)$, then $f(0)=0$. On the other hand, if $f(0)=0$, then there is a power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ such that$$(\forall z\in D(0,1)):f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n.$$So, take$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}z^n.$$

Answer (score 2):

This is possible iff $f(0)=0$. If $f(0)=0$ then the power sreies of $f$ is of the type $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_nz^{n}$ and we can take $g(z)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_nz^{n-1}$ to get $f(z)=zg(z)$. The series defining $g$ has same radius of convergence as $f$ so $g$ is holomorphic.